# How to allow desktop app and web application to connect with RDS SQL Server instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have an ASP.NET web application in a server using AWS Lightsail. This application is connected with a RDS SQL Server instance through a VPC security group (I just added the IP of my server).

Also, I have a Windows Forms application that should connect to the same RDS SQL Server instance, but the problem is that this Windows Forms application will be installed in a few computers with dynamic IP. I don't want to allow any connection to my RDS instance for security reasons but I don't know how to solve this problem with Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, you need to allow a specific IP addresses to access the database. But, the IPs are dynamic.

In this case, the only option possible is to setup a secure VPN connection and add the security group of VPN Server(either AWS managed or self managed) to the your DB server security group for that specific port.